# How to convert an NSString which is NSUTF8Encoded to NSASCIIEncoding in objective-c iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding

I have an NSString which contains data encoded with NSUTF8Encoding. I want to convert that string into NSASCIIEncoding. Please tell me anyway to convert it in a proper manner. I am able to convert reverse (NSASCIIEncoding to NSUTF8Encoding).

Please provide any sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> I have an NSString which contains data encoded with NSUTF8Encoding.

Really? <del>Because an `NSString` always treats its contents as UTF-16 internally.</del> Because you cannot be sure how an `NSString` stores its data internally. Conceptually, `NSString` works with UTF-16.

> I want to convert that string into NSASCIIStringEncoding.

```
if ([myString canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) {
    const char *asciiString = [myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: +1 the test is important because you cannot guarantee that an NSString can be converted to ASCII.

Comment: I was under the impression that `NSString`'s internal representation varied based on how the class cluster wants to optimize it. Where does Apple say that it will always be UTF-16?

Comment: Lucas: see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html: "NSString objects are conceptually UTF-16 with platform endianness. That doesn't necessarily imply anything about their internal storage mechanism; what it means is that NSString lengths, character indexes, and ranges are expressed in terms of UTF-16 units, and that the term “character” in NSString method names refers to 16-bit platform-endian UTF-16 units." – So you are at least partly correct. It's UTF-16 conceptually but doesn't define the actual storage.

Comment: Ok, I have done that. But I am not able to use that asciiString. There is Exc-Bad-Access exception is coming while I use that asciiString. What to do?